Handling Summation in Autocorrelation Function for PAM Signals with Random Shifts
I am working on the autocorrelation function of a Pulse Amplitude Modulated (PAM) signal, which is given by:
$$
X(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n p(t-n T-\phi)
$$
where:

$A_n$ are i.i.d. random variables taking values $\pm 1$ with equal probability,
$p(t)$ is a rectangular pulse of duration $T$,
$\phi$ is a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0, T]$,
$T$ is the pulse repetition period.

The autocorrelation function $R_X(\tau)$ is defined as:
$$
R_X(\tau)=\mathbb{E}[X(t) X(t+\tau)]
$$
After substituting $X(t)$, the expression becomes:
$$
R_X(\tau)=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n A_m p(t-n T-\phi) p(t+\tau-m T-\phi)\right] .
$$
Using the fact that $A_n$ are i.i.d. random variables:

$\mathbb{E}\left[A_n A_m\right]=0$ for $n \neq m$, and
$\mathbb{E}\left[A_n A_n\right]=1$ for $n=m$,
the double sum simplifies to:
$$
R_X(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[p(t-n T-\phi) p(t+\tau-n T-\phi)]
$$

Now, $\mathbb{E}[p(t-n T-\phi) p(t+\tau-n T-\phi)]$ is computed as:
$$
\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T p(t-n T-\phi) p(t+\tau-n T-\phi) d \phi,
$$
which evaluates to $\frac{1}{T}(T-|\tau|)$ for $|\tau| \leq T$.
Thus, the autocorrelation function becomes:
$$
R_X(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{T}(T-|\tau|), \quad \text { for }|\tau| \leq T .
$$
My Question:
What should I do with the summation over $n$ in the final result? Given the periodicity of the pulses and the uniform distribution of $\phi$, I expect the summation over $n$ to yield the same result for each $n$. Should I simplify this sum, and if so, how?
Also, is there any specific mathematical or conceptual step I'm missing here that would affect how I should handle the summation over $n$ in this derivation?

Hint:  $p(\cdot)$ is a rectangular pulse of duration $T$ (e.g. $p(t) = \operatorname{rect}(t)$ or $p(t)= \operatorname{rect}(t-0.5)$ and so its value is $0$ whenever its argument lies outside these limits. Thus, in
$$\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T p(t-n T-\phi) p(t+\tau-n T-\phi) d \phi$$
the integrand is $0$ whenever either of the two arguments of $p(\cdot)$
is such that it lies outside the limits. Apply this idea to get that most of the infinitely many integrals in that sum have value $0$, leaving you with
$$
R_X(\tau)= \frac{1}{T}(T-|\tau|), \quad \text { for }|\tau| \leq T 
$$
which is a symmetric triangular pulse of height $1$ and base $[-T,T]$.
For a detailed analysis that will cause you to cross your eyes and dot your teas, see this answer of mine on this site.

Your mistake lies in the integration of the product of the shifted pulses:
\begin{align*}
E\big\{p(t-nT-\phi)p(t+\tau-nT-\phi)\big\} &= \frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tp(t-nT-\phi)p(t+\tau-nT-\phi)d\phi \\
&= \frac{1}{T}\int_{t-nT}^{t-nT+T}p(x)p(x+\tau)dx
\end{align*}
where I used the substitution $x=t-nT-\phi$.
Summing over these integrals yields
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{t-nT}^{t-nT+T}p(x)p(x+\tau)dx=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)p(x+\tau)dx$$
which will give you the desired result.
[This answer is equivalent to Dilip's answer, which I just saw after writing up this one.]

+1 Actually, I like your answer better since it applies even when $p(t)$ is not a pulse of duration $T$ and so can be used even for determining the autocorrelation function of a received signal with ISI. My own version of the $\int p(x)p(x+\tau) dx$ formula is in this other answer of mine which I cite in the last sentence of my answer above.
